# Flatmap chain how to make it simple

Tags: typescript, lodash

I have written set of functions, that makes what I want. But I'd lie to ask you if there is a way to make is nicer, more efficient.

```
const selectedOptions = this.listOption.map(option => option.selectedOptions.selected);
const values = _.flatMap(selectedOptions).map((option: MatListOption) => option.value);
```

so there is a map, then there is flatmap and map again...

Comment: Please include input the data, and expected result.

Comment: The first `.map()` and `.flatMap()` can be combined (such a question would be more appropriate on https://codereview.stackexchange.com - but before posting this tiny bit of code you really should have a look at their help section and how to ask a good question. They have very specific rules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only things that come to mind would be to cut down on the first `map` and instead combine it into `_.flatMap()`. Also, you can get rid of the intermediate variable by directly chaining.

```
const values = _.flatMap(this.listOption, option => option.selectedOptions.selected)
   .map(option => option.value);
```